# Weirdly specific problems running Python script on Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, git-bash

I made a simple script for registering retirement dates for people.

It runs fine in Git-Bash, but: if I try to run it in CMD or PowerShell, it unexpectedly quits right before the second part (begginning with 'for person in register:').

UNLESS, that is, if I open it with administrator privileges.

It also fails if I turn it into as an executable file with pyinstaller.

I would appreciate any help.

Windows 10 Python 3.9

Here is the code:

```
person = {}
register = []
i = 0
v = None

while True:
    i += 1
    person['n'] = i
    person['name'] = str(input('Name: '))
    person['ybirth'] = int(input('Year of birth: '))
    person['ssn'] = str(input('Social security: '))
    if person['ssn'] != '' and person['ssn'] != '0':
        person['hire'] = input('First hired (year): ')
        person['inc'] = input('Last income: ')
    else:
        person['ssn'] = None
        person['hire'] = None
        person['inc'] = None
    register.append(person.copy())
    v = str(input('Do you wish to add another person (s/n)? '))
    if v != 's':
        break
    else:
        pass

for person in register:
        
    n = int(person['n'])
    name = person['name']
    ybirth = int(person['ybirth'])
    age = int(2021 - ybirth)
    inc = person['inc']
    
    if person['ssn'] == None:
        
        p = str(f'''
    {n}) Name: {name}
    Year of birth: {ybirth} ({age} years)
    Social security number: not available
    ---------------------------------------------
        ''')
    
    else:
        ssn = str(person['ssn'])
        hire = int(person['hire'])
        apos = int(hire + 35)
        agrt = int(age + 35)
        
        p = str(f'''
    {n}) Name: {name}
    Year of birth: {ybirth} ({age} years)
    Social security number: {ssn}
    Last income: {inc}
    First hired (year): {hire}
    Retiremente {apos}, at age {agrt}
    ---------------------------------------------
        ''')

    print(p)
    
print('Thank you!')
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Tangentially, `else: pass` is useless; just leave out the `else:` if you don't have anything you want to put there.

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible. Do you get a traceback or something?

Comment: @tripleee I'm a beginner. I don't know what a traceback is. Would you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's the message printed by Python when it terminates because of an error. It helps you see which precise line of code the error happened on and the function calls which were in progress at the time. (This should be very easy to google.)